# Distinct values of a particular field from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am querying a collection to get a few fields:

```
db.item.find({eventID:ObjectId("xxx"),deleted:false})
```

How do I filter my results to get the distinct values of a particular field in hiss query. Lets say I want only distinct values of a field 'itemId' from the result of the above query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/#db.collection.distinct) command for that:

```js
db.item.distinct('itemId', {eventID:ObjectId("xxx"), deleted:false})
```