# Select all distinct subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I am have the next document collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568dc77473bf57f465da61dd"), "name" : "Rama", "items" : [ { "id" : 40, "name" : "Botella" }, { "id" : 30, "name" : "Frasco" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("568dc78873bf57f465da61de"), "name" : "Pepe", "items" : [ { "id" : 40, "name" : "Botella" }, { "id" : 29, "name" : "Cigarrillo" } ] }
```

Each document have a collection of items. Each item is a document. So i have the list of all distinct items on the collection:

```
{ "id" : 40, "name" : "Botella" }, 
{ "id" : 29, "name" : "Cigarrillo" },
{ "id" : 30, "name" : "Frasco" }
```

With $unwind i obtained one item per document:

```
db.test.aggregate([{'$unwind': '$items'}, {'$project': {'items.id': 1, 'items.name': 1, '_id': 0}}])
{ "items" : { "id" : 40, "name" : "Botella" } }
{ "items" : { "id" : 30, "name" : "Frasco" } }
{ "items" : { "id" : 40, "name" : "Botella" } }
{ "items" : { "id" : 29, "name" : "Cigarrillo" } }
```

But now, i don't know how get the distinct 'items'. I am doing my first steps with MongoDB.

Any ideas ?

Comment: use simple `distinct` as `db.collection.distinct("items")`

Comment: Great !!! Works fine :) Thank you. Post an answer !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Distinct values of a particular field from MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21193478/distinct-values-of-a-particular-field-from-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You can group on the `items.id` and `items.name` to get the distinct items

```
db.test.aggregate([
     {'$unwind': '$items'}, 
     {'$group': {'_id':{'id':'$items.id', 'name':'$items.name'}}},
     {'$project': {'items': '$_id', '_id':0}}])
```